# When I export the backup, I get the error: No such file or directory

Tags: untagged

I export data as [office docs](https://docs.cnosdb.com/zh/latest/manage/backup_restore.html#export), sync as follow:

```
cnosdb-imexport export --src <user>:<password>@<ip>:<port> --path ./backup
```

and I run cmd as follow:

```
./target/release/cnosdb-imexport export -s root:@127.0.0.1:8902 --path ./test
```

but the log:

```
# Input args: Cli { subcmd: Export(ExportArgs { src: "root:@127.0.0.1:8902", path: "./test", conn: None }) }
# Begin  export table(t001.db001.air)  [Now: 10:36:54]
# Export table(t001.db001.air) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: IO error: No such file or directory (os error 2)"}
```

I check current dir:

```
cnosdb-enterprise git:(main) ✗ ll | grep test
drwxr-xr-x   2 xxx  staff    0B 12 25 10:36 test
```

The test directory does exist, what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug described in the documentation, the correct as follow:

```
cnosdb-imexport export --src <user>:<password>@<ip>:<port> --path file:///backup
```

Comment: If it's described in the documentation, it's not a bug.